# How to add custom meta data to the Order Items in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this hook and adding custom meta data but it's not working. Can you please tell me how can i add custom meta data to the Order Items in woocommerce.

```
 add_action('woocommerce_new_order_item','all_add_values_to_order_item_meta',10,3);
    function all_add_values_to_order_item_meta($item_id,$values){
    if(!empty($values['tbb_right_sphere'])){
            $tbb_right_sphere=$values['tbb_right_sphere'];
    wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id,'od_right_sphere',$tbb_right_sphere);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **woocommerce_add_order_item_meta** hook so your code will be looks like this.

```
 add_action('woocommerce_add_order_item_meta','all_add_values_to_order_item_meta',10,3); // add extra order metas
```

`function all_add_values_to_order_item_meta($item_id,$values)
    {
       if(!empty($values['tbb_right_sphere']))
       {
        $tbb_right_sphere=$values['tbb_right_sphere'];
       wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id,'od_right_sphere',$tbb_right_sphere);
       }
   }`

Comment: when i using this hook it works but also error log generate  **The "woocommerce_add_order_item_meta" hook uses out of date data structures and function is deprecated since version 3.2.5. Replace with woocommerce_new_order_item.** 

`add_action('woocommerce_add_order_item_meta','all_add_values_to_order_item_meta',10,3); `

can you please guide me how it works without any error